# How many four-digit positive integers are there that contain the digit $3$ and are divisible by $5$?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

> How many four-digit positive integers are there that contain the digit $3$ and are divisible by $5$?

The answer is: 
the  number of four-digit integers that are divisible by $5\;-\;$ the number of four-digit integers that are divisible by $5$ and not contain the digit $3$

So, $9\cdot10\cdot10\cdot2-8\cdot 9\cdot 9\cdot 2=1800-1296=504\tag{*}$

I know that, but when I tried to solve this problem with an other way I got a different result.

Four digit integers : $\overline{xyzw}$
Suppose $\overline{xyzw}$ contain at least one digit equal $3$

So, $x = \{1, \ldots ,9\}, y = 3, z = \{0, \ldots, 9\}, w = \{0,5\}$

or $x = \{1, \ldots, 9\}, y = \{0, \ldots, 9\}, z = 3, w = \{0,5\}$

or $x = 3, y=\{0, \ldots, 9\}, z = \{0, \ldots, 9\}, w = \{0,5\}$

The number of all $\overline{xyzw}$ that must be divisible by $5$ and contain $3$ is: $9\cdot 10\cdot 2+9\cdot 10\cdot 2+10\cdot 10\cdot 2=180+180+200=560\tag{**}$

but (*) contradicts (**), so where is the mistake?

Comment: Your second method counts each four-digit number as many times as the number $3$ appears in the number.  There are $1 \cdot 1 \cdot 9 \cdot 2 + 1 \cdot 9 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 + 8 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 = 18 + 18 + 16 = 52$ numbers in which the digit three appears exactly twice and $1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 = 2$ numbers in which the digit three appears three times, so your second method added $52 + 2 \cdot 2 = 52 + 4 = 56$ to the correct total.

Answer (score 4):

You double counted, for example $3335$ appears in all your sum.

You can use inclusion-exclusion to adjust your count.

\begin{align}
&|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A \cap C|-|B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C|\\
&=560 - 18 - 20-20+2\\
&=504
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

You are over counting a few cases. For example, $1330$ is counted in the first case when  $x\in\{1,…,9\},y=3,z\in\{0,…,9\},w\in\{0,5\}$ and it is counted again in the second case when $x\in\{1,…,9\},y\in\{0,…,9\},z=3,w\in\{0,5\}$